# UDP broadcast in C

Tags: c, udp, broadcast

When I broadcast a message by the code below, the server on the host machine also receive the message, how can I prevent host machine to receive the message that it sends?

Is it possible to change something on the code or would it be better to use something like `if (strcmp(hostIP == IP_of_the_package) == 0) { <discard the msg>}`? the host machine gets IP from DHCP, how can I define `hostIP as a variable` and How can I extract `IP addr of the packet`?

```
void boardcast_msg(char *mess){
   int sock;                        
   struct sockaddr_in broadcastAddr; 
   char *broadcastIP;                
   unsigned short broadcastPort;     
   char *sendString;                 
   int broadcastPermission;         
   int sendStringLen;                

   broadcastIP = "255.255.255.255";  
   broadcastPort = 33333;

   sendString = mess;             /*  string to broadcast */


   if ((sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) < 0){
       fprintf(stderr, "socket error");
        exit(1);
   }


   broadcastPermission = 1;
   if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, (void *) &broadcastPermission,sizeof(broadcastPermission)) < 0){
       fprintf(stderr, "setsockopt error");
       exit(1);
   }

   /* Construct local address structure */
   memset(&broadcastAddr, 0, sizeof(broadcastAddr));   
   broadcastAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;                 
   broadcastAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(broadcastIP);
   broadcastAddr.sin_port = htons(broadcastPort);       

   sendStringLen = strlen(sendString);  

        /* Broadcast sendString in datagram to clients */
        if (sendto(sock, sendString, sendStringLen, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&broadcastAddr, sizeof(broadcastAddr)) != sendStringLen){
            fprintf(stderr, "sendto error");
            exit(1);
        }

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disabling self-reception of UDP broadcasts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499237/disabling-self-reception-of-udp-broadcasts)

Answer (score 2):

Disable loopback so you do not receive your own datagrams:

```
char loopch=0;

if (setsockopt(sd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_LOOP,
               (char *)&loopch, sizeof(loopch)) < 0) {
  perror("setting IP_MULTICAST_LOOP:");
  close(sd);
  exit(1);
}
```

from: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzab6%2Frzab6x1multicast.htm

Comment: This is about *multicast*, not *broadcast*.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, you need to see if a received package is from your self, and then discard it.

The simplest way to get the local hosts address is to use `gethostname` and `gethostbyname`. These will however not work well if your host has multiple hostnames or IP addresses. Search SO (or Google) for how to get all possible network addresses.

Answer (score -1):

your program's broadcast destination port should be blocked on your machine to avoid receiving self broadcasts.

in your `iptables` you can drop the (`TCP` or `UDP` as required ) packets received on that port.

Comment: Never a good idea to alter global state to solve a local problem.

Comment: I would argue that this prevents creating closed loops for a user defined protocol e.g. TLV (type/lenght/value ) based UDP tunnel management protocols

Answer (score -1):

`recvfrom` will give you an address.  Use that.

As for what addresses to match against, on many systems (probably the ones you care about) you can get local IP addresses with `getifaddrs`.  However this is not in POSIX.