# How to broadcast over UDP Sockets?

Tags: c, sockets, udp, broadcasting

I am trying to broadcast messages over registered multiple client over UDP protocol.

I believe we need below two commands for sending and receiving over sockets :

```
sendto(sock,buffer,
            strlen(buffer),0,(const struct sockaddr *)&server,length);

recvfrom(sock,buffer,256,0,(struct sockaddr *)&from, &length);
```

As we can see , we need 6 argument for same, second last being the the address of recipient. In case of client to server , we have address.
But from server to client we only have address of last client from which message have received.

**I had also tried storing the addresses of all sockets who connect to server atleast once , so that we can use sendto(), But as all client are running on same machine, That `&from` seems to be same.**

What are alternatives available ? Where am I going wrong ? I simply want to broadcast a message to all client running on local machine. ?

Comment: I'm confused. Do you mean `multicast` instead of `broadcast`?

Comment: I want to send message to all clients at the same time.

Comment: check the `struct sockaddr_in` structure. There is something called _port number_ [`sin_port`].

Comment: That would be same for connection, right ? As there is only one server.

Comment: So? your problem is in server side, am I right? Please add some more information and localize your problem in hand.

Comment: @Manish You can do that with 2 methods, IP broadcast or IP multicast, where you send to a special IP address - that the clients also need be prepared to receive from. IP broadcast can only be done on the same IP subnet(LAN), IP multicast can go beyond a single IP subnet(but requires special configuration of your routers to do so). You need to first chose one of those 2 methods. Or you perform the broadcast yourself in code, but calling sendto() in a loop for each of your clients.

Comment: @nos , thanks for your time. They all are on same subnet. on the same machine to be more correct.  When you say , special IP , could you please elaborate. Also as I told , I can't use sendto() in loop as every client have same address .

Comment: @SouravGhosh I guess , you misunderstood my question. I am not receiving any error. I just don't know how to proceed for my idea.

Comment: You can perhaps find some hints from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747107/udp-broadcast-in-c

Comment: But. It is sender and has address. It does not comment anything on receiver side. how will all clients will receive if sent to single address and port. I am more concerned about multiple receivers.

Answer (score 0):

Sending UDP broadcasts might not be allowed by default by you network stack implementation. You need to enable broadcast in some environments:

```
int allow_broadcast = 1;
setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, (void*) &allow_broadcast, sizeof(allow_broadcast));
```

The actual parameter list of setsockopt should be available in the documentation of your OS like [1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms740476(v=vs.85).aspx) or [2](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setsockopt).